# how to calculate possible combinations [Special Case]

Tags: combinations, integers

lets say we have an array of $n$ indexes each which can be any number(integers only ) provided the that total sum of all indexes is exactly equals to $c$ in each different combination is there any way to calculate the total count of possible combinations ?

eg : we have array1 that has 10 indexes $\{33,10,4,15,18,5,5,9,1,0 \}$ the total sum equals to $100$ how many arrays I will be able to generate that has the total sum of $100$ each ?

Comment: what do you mean by any number reals,integers, naturals ? whole numbers ? complex numbers ? quaternions ? octonians ?

Comment: sorry integers only

Comment: surely you mean non-negative integers ( whole numbers)

Comment: Stars and Bars gives the number of n-tuples of whole numbers summing to N as $\binom{N+n-1}{n-1}$. I don't know how to get the number of combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k1 = 0}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{k_{10} = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{100}}z^{k_{1} + \cdots + k_{10}} & =
\bracks{z^{100}}\pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{k}}^{10} =
\bracks{z^{100}}\pars{1 - z}^{-10} = {-10 \choose 100}\pars{-1}^{100}
\\[5mm] & =
{-\bracks{-10} + 100 - 1 \choose 100}\pars{-1}^{100} = {109 \choose 100}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{109 \choose 9} = 4,263,421,511,271
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you view the order of the elements as important, you are asking for [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $100$ into $10$ parts.  The Wikipedia article on [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) shows this is $100+10-1 \choose 10-1$.  You can search the site for these terms and find many examples.

Comment: thanks , this sounds promising i'll look it up !